# ReplyURIs in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a built a .NET Console app. It uses MSAL for interacting with Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. This app is a sample to show the various ways to connect to Org, Social & Local Accounts.

I’m able to do Signup and Signin with local account without any errors. When I try with Multi Tenant Azure ID or even a single tenant, I get the following error. I’m confused as to which application is this that is missing the ReplyURL. Appreciate guidance.

**Azure AD B2C App**

- Type: Native Application
- Redirect URIs: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient`
- Custom Redirect URIs: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient`, `com.onmicrosoft.<tenantname>.MythicalB2C://redirect/path`

**Azure AD App**

- Type: Native Application
- Redirect URIs: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:00b`, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`

I get the following error when using Org Account

> Additional technical information:
>
> AADSTS50011: Reply address '' specified by the request is not a valid URL.
>
> Allowed schemes: '*'

Comment: Can you share the code where you configure Azure AD (not B2C) auth?

Comment: Here it is, hopefully this is what you were looking for
string Tenant = "mythicalbeast.onmicrosoft.com", B2C_ClientId = "XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX",PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1A_signup_signinaad";
string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(B2C_ClientId, Authority, tokenCache);

Comment: string Tenant = "mythicalbeast.onmicrosoft.com", B2C_ClientId = "XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX",PolicySignUpSignIn = "B2C_1A_signup_signinaad";
string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(B2C_ClientId, Authority, tokenCache);

Comment: That's for B2C, what about for regular AAD? Or are you using B2C custom policies to add AAD as an IdP in B2C?

Comment: If you're doing AAD as an IdP in B2C, your AAD app needs to be a Web App, not a Native Client app as [per the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom#create-an-azure-ad-app) and it needs to have the correct replyURL, exactly as per these same instructions.

Comment: Thank you got it. So, in summary as of today, B2C with AAD IDP support is not supported for Mobile Apps. What's recommended as option for ISVs with Mobile\Native Apps that want to use B2C (Signin) and AAD in a single App?

Comment: It is supported for mobile apps. More precisely, your mobile app doesn't care about the IdP because, as far as it is concerned, it only integrates with Azure AD B2C. B2C will then integrate with other things and the mobile app doesn't care or need to do anything.

Comment: So while your mobile app uses a "native app" registration to talk to B2C. B2C itself uses a "web app" registration to talk to the IdPs it integrates with (Facebook, Google, regular Azure AD).

Comment: Why does a 'Native App' need a Redirect Uri?  There's nothing to redirect in a native (or mobile) application, so I don't understand why this is even an attribute of the 'Native' B2C client.